# How to edit groups of tasks in Microsoft project?

Tags: ms-project-2013

I want to change hundreds of tasks in a project from "fixed work" to "fix duration" type.

- When I select multiple tasks - the "Information" dialog changes only one if them.
- I have also tried to add a "type" column to the list of tasks and copy-paste the necessary type there. But, for some reason, it works not for all the tasks, most of them, although changeable one-by-one, remain unchanged if I try to past a value, copied from another row.

Could anybody show a solution? Preferably with a screenshot from Project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I showed the "Type" column, changed the first entry to "Fixed Duration", then dragged that value down through the rest of the rows, and it worked.

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2:

[image]

Step 3: click in the "Fixed Duration" field in Row 1, point to the bottom right corner and drag the field to the other rows.

[image]

Then you can hide the "Type" column again.

Answer (score 0):

I effectively solved the issue by a very simple macros: just add this text into macros Sub, save macros and then run it over selected tasks.
If necessary - change task type in the macros.

```
Dim ProjTasks As Tasks
Dim ProjTask As Task


If ActiveSelection = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Choose tasks to change type"
    Exit Sub
End If

For Each ProjTask In ActiveSelection.Tasks
    If ProjTask.Summary = False Then
        ProjTask.Type = pjFixedDuration

    End If
Next ProjTask
```

But I still wonder whether there is a standard solution